# Multiple bootstrap carousels same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have 3 bootstrap carousels on one page.

**They are being generated by a php loop that I don't have any control of so the `id` is always starts off at `carousel`.**

so the problem I am running into is that all the carousels start off with the `id="#carousel-1"` and control `href="#carousel-1"`

Of course this doesnt work as all the carousels will just scroll the first carousel i realize this wont work so I figured adding

```
$('.second-block #carousel').attr("id","#carousel-2").find('.controls a').attr("href","#carousel-2");
$('.fourth-block #carousel').attr("id","#carousel-3").find('.controls a').attr("href","#carousel-3");
```

This jquery would fix the problem as it changes the `id`'s of the other carousels to their own but unfortunately this still is only sliding carousel number one. Any ideas?

Here is a [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/bVZVaK?editors=101)

Comment: `Id` must be unique.

Comment: they still are thats what the jquery does, just change dynamically at load

Comment: You add it in php loop.

Comment: I am asking if there is any other way besides the php loop

Comment: You don't need to give me -1

Comment: Can't you edit your php script to load them with their correct `id`s and `href`s? That would be the best and cleanest way to go. Why don't you want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `id` elements of `.carousel-control`, `.carousel`. According to [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute):

> The id attribute
>
> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

Check this: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/yofkxjrv/)

```
$('.second-block').find(".carousel").attr("id", "carousel2");
$('.second-block').find('.carousel-control').attr("href", "#carousel2");
$('.third-block').find(".carousel").attr("id", "carousel3");
$('.third-block').find('.carousel-control').attr("href", "#carousel3");
```

Comment: As i stated though the ids are being generated by a php loop that i cannot control so i cant change the ids directly they all start with `carousel` thats why i use javascript to change them after the php is loaded

Comment: @NooBskie Does it fix your peoblem?

Comment: yayy thanks, how come my javascript wasnt working wasnt it doing essentially the same thing?

Comment: Your selector was wrong. It does not select target  elements and I advise you, have patience.